# How to plot a linear regression between two vertical abline?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm doing an application on shiny, and I want to plot the linear regression only between two vertical abline that I could modify with sliders.

How can I do this?

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {


output$plot.weibull <- renderPlot({   
PlotWeibull(my.data$X, my.data$Y)
if (input$fit.weibull) {
  FitWeibull(my.data)
  abline(FitWeibull(my.data), col = "blue")
  abline(v = log(input$reg.range), col = "blue", lty = 3)
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: The question, and the solution, is very similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23115746/plotting-a-line-of-best-fit-from-where-data-starts-to-where-data-ends-in-r/). Use the `vline` x-intercepts to determine the two points instead of the data range.

Comment: Sorry, i don't find the similitude between the two questions.
Can i create a function to do what i want ? where i specify, all dots before or after the two abline, are not recognized for linear regression ?

Comment: The situation is practically identical. Instead of using `abline()` (which can not be constrained), you need to use `lines()` which will take a starting point, an ending point, and draw a line in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the line `abline(FitWeibull(my.data), col='blue')` you should have:

```
lines(log(input$reg.range), FitWeibull(log(input$reg.range)), col=blue)
```

The second argument may give you an error, because `input$reg.range` needs to be in a format that `FitWeibull()` will accept.